# C++ accelerated (Q 8-1) - Template function parameterised by another function

Tags: c++, templates

I've seen a few posts on here about the use of template functions and about questions from the book C++ Accelerated (Koeing/Moo) but none of them answer my questions so I'm hoping you can help.

The question I am struggling with is;
"The various analysis functions we wrote is Sect 6.2/110 share the same behaviour; they differ only in terms of the functions they call to calculate the final grade. Write a template function, parameterized by the type of the grading function, and use that function to evaluate the grading schemes. "

I'm still in the early stages of learning, and I would really appreciate some help with this question as I have been stuck on it for weeks and no amount of Googling has helped. Everything I have read refers to referencing, or pointers - which the book has not yet covered so I find it even more confusing.

I have included the 3 analysis functions below - and I think the question is asking me to write a template function that will replace all 3. I have written a function that I think might work - see below - but I am getting errors when I try to compile because the function write_analysis that uses all of the original analysis functions can not cope with my template function.

I am completely stuck and would really appreciate any help.

I have tried not to include to much code to start with so I hope the below is sufficient.

```
double median_analysis(const vector<Student_info>& students)
{
  vector<double> grades;
  transform(students.begin(), students.end(),back_inserter(grades), grade_aux);

  return median(grades);
}



double optimistic_median_analysis(const vector<student_info>& students){

vector<double> grades ; 

transform(students.begin(), students.end(), back_inserter(grades), optimistic_median) ;

return median(grades) ; 

}


double average_analysis(const vector<Student_info>& students)
{
 vector<double> grades;
 transform(students.begin(), students.end(),back_inserter(grades), average_grade) ;

 return median(grades);
 }
```

My template function;

```
template <typename F > double Tanalysis(F Func(const student_info&))
{

std::vector<double> grades ; 

transform(students.begin(), students.end(), back_inserter(grades), Func) ;

return median(grades) ;
 }
```

The write_analysis function;

```
    void write_analysis(ostream& out, const string& name, 
                double analysis(const vector<student_info>&), 
                const vector<student_info>& did, 
                const vector<student_info>& didnt){

    out << name << " : median(did) = " << analysis(did) <<
                   " : median(didnt) = " << analysis(didnt) << endl ; 

     }
```

Called in main.cpp as follows;

```
   write_analysis(cout, "median", median_analysis, did, didnt) ;
```

I cannot say enough how much I would appreciate some help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe that the question refers to the 1st and 3rd methods only which makes sense as they are practically the same.

Comment: To tackle this, have a think about what these 2 methods share in common and what they do not. Any common functionality can remain in the method and any differences can be handled through template specialization.

Comment: The book says to "write a an analysis function to call our `optimistic_median` function". It is this analysis function that should look like your 1st and 3rd methods, not the `optimistic_median` function itself.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I will have a another think about think and try and come up with an answer.

Comment: I have now created a optimistic_median_analysis function that has the same structure as average_analysis and median_analysis above. The only difference between the 3 functions is therefore the grade function it calls to populate the vector grade. I was think of including the grading function to used, grade_aux, average_grade and optimistic_median respectively, as an template parameter. Something like the following  template<class G >
Double analysis( G, Student_info& s)
{
     return G(s);
}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find my way to a solution in the end and thought I would share in case anyone else gets equally stuck on this one.

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm> //transform 

#include "student_info.h"
#include "median.h"

template <typename F> 
double Tanalysis(F Func, std::vector<student_info> students)
{
    std::vector<double> grades ; 

   transform(students.begin(), students.end(), back_inserter(grades), Func) ;

   return median(grades) ;
}
```

The above template works by itself in main.cpp called as follows;

```
double ans = Tanalysis(grade_aux,did) ;
double ans2 = Tanalysis(grade_aux, didnt) ; 

cout << "And the Answer for did is: " << ans <<
    ". The Answer for didnt is: " << ans2 << endl ;
```

To get it to work with the write_analysis function I had to template that as well.

```
template <typename F, typename F2>
void Twrite_analysis(ostream& out, const string& name, F Func, F2 Func2)
{
    out << name << " : median(did) = " << Func <<
                   " : median(didnt) = " << Func2 << endl ; 
}
```

called as follows in main.cpp;

```
Twrite_analysis(cout, "median", Tanalysis(grade_aux, did), Tanalysis(grade_aux, didnt));
```

This was the best solution I could come up with, but if anyone has any comments on how to improve it that would be good.